# How to check if a spawner is broken in Minecraft 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So the new 1.14 update seems to have changed a lot of commands (again). All I'm trying to do is detect when the player breaks a spawner in a specific location. Say for example the spawner is at -200 20 10, how can I check if that spawner is broken and run a command?

I've tried the command `/execute if block -217 64 -220 #minecraft:spawner run say hello` as a test in a repeating command block, and for some reason, it won't check for one. I've even tried entity, but the only option is checking for a minecart spawner. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Why did you use a `#`? There is no "`spawner`" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there is a spawner at certain coordinates, you can test if there's **air** there instead of testing if there's a spawner. Logically, there will be air in the place of the spawner when it breaks, so we don't need to identify spawners using commands at all.

Here's what the command looks like if there's a spawner at coordinates `x:0 y:70 z:0`:

```
/execute if block 0 70 0 minecraft:air
```

By the way, the following command worked for me:

```
/execute if block 0 70 0 minecraft:spawner
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really strange, I must've set the wrong location or something, but I tried that command and nothing worked. Oh well, it's working now, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: This solution is unreliable, someone might instantly put another block there. I recommend `/execute unless block 0 70 0 spawner`.

Comment: @FabianRoling Yeah, I’m pretty sure that there’s at least one mod that lets you overwrite the blocks in a location with blocks of the player’s choosing. Or without mods, they might bury the spawned with fluid blocks then break the spawned, causing it to be filled with a flowing fluid block.

Comment: @nick012000 Much easier, just use your "use" key with a block in your offhand as soon as you're done mining. If it's withing 0.05 seconds, it's instant for the server.

Comment: @FabianRöling You're right in that, but I just  found the next most reliable method besides testing for a spawner, which didn't work for Daniel

Comment: Thanks everyone for the solutions.